# Trying to run files on Ubuntu from televsion

Tags: ubuntu, laptop, hdmi, tv

I am using a TV with HDMI input from sony laptop running ubuntu 12.  I can see the screen on the TV but any files I run on the laptop do not appear on the television.  Any ideas what I might be doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the small amount of information you've given, it seems like you've extended your display instead of mirroring it.

I would suggested trying to drag an open window to the left/right/bottom and top of your laptop screen to see if it appears on your TV.

Comment: yes, you're right and thanks for sharing.  It was extending at the time but now it mirrors.  I have to raise another question for the sound not being played but judging by the downvoter extremists on the site, I have to wonder whether I should do that or not.